# Network Printer support?

Tags: iphone, airprint

It might be a duplicate question. But after i have read the many questions related to this topic, i'm not convinced with the answers and querying it here. Please help me to get concrete answer for this.
How to support network wifi printer in an iPhone application to print a page or document?
I want to access network printer in my iPhone application and push some pages to print from my iPhone app to Printer?

1. Is it possible? How to do that? 
   I saw in the forum answers that we need to first build a desktop application, then iPhone app can push the data to the desktop app, then desktop app will be able to push the data lastly to the printer.
2. Is it the way do it? If yes, can't we access printer and push the page to the printer directly from my iPhone app?
3. From what version API's are supported for printer access?

Please help me by giving answers if you know about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best answer:

Use/wait for iOS 4.2, and use the new "AirPrint" support.

Comment: I actually recently added AirPrint support to one of my applications. It is very slick! Fairly easy to do - you can pass a bunch of different formats to AirPrint including PNG, HTML, Text or PDF - and "It Just Works™"!